# Change package margins within a section of the document

Tags: margins

I am using a style file that I found for a CV but I need to include the cover letter with the CV in a single file. So I am just putting the cover letter on the first page. The margins though are too small on the right hand side. So how can I override this and put more space on that side?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be easier to make your CV and cover letter separate documents and use a PDF utility to combine them.  The PDF utility could be LaTeX with the [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) package.

Comment: Or, as an alternative pdftk (http://www.pdfhacks.com/pdftk/) is an excellent tool for combining pdf files (and much more).

Comment: @hlovdal:perfect!

Comment: There's also Acrobat (Pro, not regular), and Mac Preview that can combine with a GUI.

Comment: There also exist GUIs for PDFtk.

Answer (score 4):

Matthew's suggestion is the preferable solution. However, since version 5 of [geometry](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) it is possible to alter the page dimensions within a document. The package manual has the details.

Answer (score 0):

Get the latex file as a pdf in overleaf.com. Then add the latex pdf file that was created and the pdf file you want to insert with the program "PDF binder" (I know it can be downloaded to windows 10 at least).

If you want to add yor appendix somewhere other than at the end of the latex pdf file, then print part of the latex pdf file as a pdf, then add your appendix, and then the rest of the latex pdf file in the program "pdf binder".

I think there are some webpages that can be used instead of the program "PDF binder".

---

This question ([Merge two PDF files output by LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8662/merge-two-pdf-files-output-by-latex)) is similar.

These are also useful:

[Insert PDF file in LaTeX document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105589/insert-pdf-file-in-latex-document)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739159/inserting-a-pdf-file-in-latex/67191285#67191285