# Merge two PDF files output by LaTeX?

Tags: pdf

I would like to (re)submit a paper with a short cover letter, explaining the changes I have made.  However, the journal only allows me to upload one file.  As the main article will use the journal style class, and so forth, it's not really practical to use the 1st page for the letter (or is it?  Could I reset the page number etc. etc.??)

Instead, could I create, say, two PDF files (one the letter, the other the article) and then somehow merge them together?

Comment: Hi Matthew, welcome to tex.SX!  If you tell us what operating system you're using then that would help as the ways to do this vary from OS to OS.

Comment: Well, I have a very up-to-date version of MikTex on Windows, and also a rather old Linux system at work...

Comment: Would zipping the two files together into one archive suffice, or has your one uploaded file got to be a pdf?

Comment: Same question on SuperUser: [Adobe Acrobat: How to batch to combine multiple pdf files? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/389760/adobe-acrobat-how-to-batch-to-combine-multiple-pdf-files)

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Create the separate documents separately and merge them with a PDF utility.  Semantically speaking, I feel this is the way to go rather than futzing with the document settings.  After all, what you are submitting is not one "document" but a set of them.

**Edit:** This is an important question that has been asked more than once.  It's also not exactly TeX-related.  So I'm community-wikifying my answer so it can be improved and made definitive.

#### LaTeX

use Herbert's answer: the [pdfpages](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) package

```
\documentclass{article}% or something else
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{paper1}
\includepdf[pages=-]{paper2}

\end{document}
```

You could also keep the document page sizes by adding a option:

```
\includepdf[pages=-,fitpaper]{paper1}
\includepdf[pages=-,fitpaper]{paper2}
```

And not to repeat yourself use this:

```
\includepdfset{pages=-,fitpaper}
\includepdf{paper1}
\includepdf{paper2}
\includepdf{paper3}
\includepdf[fitpaper=false]{paper4} // you can add document specific options
\includepdf{paper5}
\includepdf{paper6}
\includepdfset{} // to put default values back
```

#### Command Line

- [`pdftk`](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/)

  ```
   $ pdftk 1.pdf 2.pdf 3.pdf cat output 123.pdf
  ```
- [GhostScript](http://www.ghostscript.com/)

  ```
   $ gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=merged.pdf source1.pdf source2.pdf source3.pdf etc.pdf
  ```

  (via [Macworld](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2003083122212228))
- [PDFJAM](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam/) is a suite of scripts that uses LaTeX and pdfpages on the backend.

  ```
   $ pdfjoin foo1.pdf foo2.pdf --outfile bar.pdf
  ```

  (via [Uwe Hermann](http://www.hermann-uwe.de/blog/manipulating-pdfs-from-the-command-line-joining-merging-rotating))
- [`stapler`](https://github.com/hellerbarde/stapler) is a pure Python alternative to `pdftk`.

  ```
    $ stapler cat in1.pdf in2.pdf out.pdf
  ```
- [PyMuPDF](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module.html#joining-pdf-documents) is a Python binding for [MuPDF](http://www.mupdf.com/) – “a lightweight PDF and XPS viewer”.

  ```
     $ python -m fitz join -o output.pdf file1.pdf file2.pdf
  ```
- [`qpdf`](https://qpdf.sourceforge.io/) is a command-line tool and C++ library that performs content-preserving transformations on PDF files.

  ```
      $ qpdf --empty --pages file1.pdf file2.pdf -- output.pdf
  ```

#### GUI

- Preview (Mac only) [example](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20071114191806624)
- Acrobat Pro (non-free) [video example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Aj8VRt0v6c)
- [GUIPDFTK](http://www.paehl.de/pdf/gui_pdftk.html)
- [PDFCreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator) (Win only, free, Open Source, acts like a printer ⇒ no hyperlinks etc.)
- [PDF Mod](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/PdfMod) (Linux, free software)
- [PDF-Shuffler](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfshuffler/) (Linux, free software)
- [PDFsam](https://pdfsam.org/) (JRE - Windows, Linux, Mac, free and non-free versions)

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5842/1402) is very similar although the questioner didn't realize it.

Comment: Beat me to it on `pdftk`; a very useful little program for mucking about with PDFs.

Comment: I'll accept this; actually, I guess I should have search harder, as that other question was almost identical to mine!  Many thanks to all.

Comment: Am I the only one who has trouble with the output of pdftk working well with ghostcript? Ghostscript complains that pdftk output violates the PDF spec. I prefer the pdfjam scripts, which provide similar commandline functionality, but uses pdflatex/pdfpages for its backend. (For that matter, gs can itself combine PDFs from the commandline.)

Comment: @frabjous: I haven't had any problems with pdftk (which I've just been playing with); but also using gs directly works!

Comment: Note that `pdfpages` removes all hyperlinks and other PDF annotations from the included PDFs.

Comment: I added PDFCreator as another GUI option. With the answer being CW, I hope that's ok.

Comment: PDF Mod is a very nice application, but it seems to have problems opening LaTeX documents.

Comment: The ghostscript option worked well for me on MacOS, preserving the url hyperlinks (did not have any internal document links to check) in the final output.

Comment: I was using pdftk but some times i ggt increase heapsize error. HOw to solve this

Comment: One problem with pdfpages is the pages size are all changed to article. If my pdf has inbetween different page sizes it does not consider that

Comment: Even if we use `fitpaper` option  for `includepdf (pdfpages)` it will consider the first page as the page size for all the paages. –

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi: That's another good reason to use a native PDF utility instead.

Comment: I generally use either `pdftk` ( Java and C++) or `stapler` (python pypdf based).

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi: Stapler is a new one for me.  Can you add it to the post? (It's CW)

Comment: Can we add [qpdf](https://qpdf.sourceforge.io/), which I think is a really nice tool and doesn't mangle forms and bookmarks: `qpdf  --empty --pages file1.pdf file2.pdf -- output.pdf`

Comment: @frabjous: Go right ahead. Please add it in and include a line of usage for easy copying/pasting.

Answer (score 28):

Package `pdfpages`may help

```
\documentclass{article}% or something else
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=...]{paper1}
\includepdf[pages=...]{paper2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works fine as well (once I noticed the typo: "includepdf" not "inlcudepdf"!)  Actually, maybe this is the "nicest" way to do a cover letter, as then I can just include the PDF file of paper at the end.

Comment: @Matthew: I had a knot in my fingers ... :-)

Comment: I have clickable links in the PDF that I want to include. They are gone in the merged PDF. How can I maintain these links? ... Ah ok, seems like it's not possible.

Comment: @CGFoX: pdftk seems to keep internal links.

Answer (score 8):

If you have Ghostscript installed, you might also join the two separate PDF files in one by issuing a command such as this:

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=merged.pdf input1.pdf input2.pdf
```