# Create a three parts page layout

Tags: minipage, layout

I want to write a latex document that consists of only 1 A4 page, which is based on the `article` document class, and has the following layout:

[image]

Inside each "box", I need to be able to insert almost anything. Not just text, but also graphics, tikzpicture, list environment and also footnotes (there will be no floats).

How can I do that?

My approach is to create 3 `minipage`s, as in the MWE below, and to type the content inside them.

Is this approach good? Is there a better way to achieve this page layout?

If yes, then I would like to know why I still get an `Overfull \hbox` warning in my code.

```latex
\documentclass[a4]{article}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setlength\voffset{0pt}        \setlength\headsep{0pt}
\setlength\headheight{0pt}     \setlength\topmargin{0pt}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}      \setlength\marginparsep{0pt}
\setlength\marginparwidth{0pt}

\usepackage[textheight=0.9\paperheight,showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[b][2in][c]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}
\center {\Huge Content that extends 100\% of the {\ttfamily textwidth}}
\end{minipage}
}%

\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t][][c]{\dimexpr 0.65\textwidth-2\fboxsep}
\center {\Huge Content that extends 65\% of the {\ttfamily textwidth}}
\end{minipage}
}%
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t][][c]{\dimexpr 0.35\textwidth-2\fboxsep}
\center {\Huge Content that extends 35\% of the {\ttfamily textwidth}}
\end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: there is not an a4 option so this is not A4  but you have 4\fboxsep and 4\fboxrule width in addition to (.65+.35)\textwith

Comment: `\center` is not a command (it is part of `\begin{center}` and does not take an argument. `\center {foo}` applies to the rest of the document, not `foo`

Comment: you have spaces after `\end{minipage}` add `%`

Comment: @DavidCarlise ok, so I got a few things to correct here. But, is the usage of `minipage`s to achieve this apperance of the document considered as a good approach?

Comment: yes, why not?  `\begin{minipage}[t][][c]` should be `\begin{minipage}[t]` though.

Comment: Would be simpler to create 3 pdfs and just stich them together ?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8662/merge-two-pdf-files-output-by-latex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest to use a `tcbposter`. You can define several `tcbposter` boxes and write whatever you want inside. In this case, there are three boxes over one column. The top box (`A`) and two lober boxes, `B` and `C`, whith speceific widths and being `C` aligned to the right. These two boxes are defined to occupy all the space between the top box and the bottom of the page. Backgorund colors are shown to easily understand the geometry.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\noindent\begin{tcbposter}[%
    poster = {columns=1,spacing=0pt},
    boxes = {sharp corners, boxrule=0pt}
]
\posterbox[colback=red!10]{name=A, below=top}{Some text on top
\begin{enumerate}
\item One
\item Two
\end{enumerate}}
\posterbox[colback=blue!10]{name=B, span=0.65, between=A and bottom}{\lipsum[1-2]
{\par\centering\includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-a}\par}}
\posterbox[colback=green!10]{name=C, column*=1, span=0.35, between=A and bottom}{\lipsum[2]
{\par\centering\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[fill=red!20, minimum size=2cm, draw=blue, thick]{A};
\end{tikzpicture}\par}}
\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach using `tabularray` package

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setlength\voffset{0pt}        \setlength\headsep{0pt}
\setlength\headheight{0pt}     \setlength\topmargin{0pt}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}      \setlength\marginparsep{0pt}
\setlength\marginparwidth{0pt}

\usepackage[textheight=0.9\paperheight,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\SetTblrInner{%
    width=\textwidth,
    colspec={X[0.65,c]X[0.35,c]},
    cell{1}{1} = {c=2}{},
    colsep=0pt,
    rowsep=0pt,
    rows={font=\Large},
    row{1}={rowsep=20pt},
    hlines,
    vlines,
    verb
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{}
     Content that extends to 100\% of \verb!\textwidth!
     \\\hline
     Content that extends to 65\% of \verb!\textwidth!
     &  
     Content that extends to 35\% of \verb!\textwidth!
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Which result with

[image]