# Combine two papers into one PDF file

Tags: merge

I need to combine two main latex files (one is the paper with the implemented comments from the reviewers, and the other is the response to the reviewers).
They want a single pdf file with the letter first and the paper second.

How can I combine them using latex without generating the pdf? (Overleaf does not save the pdf in the main folder)

I tried to make a separate "Merge.tex" file including both "paper.tex" and "letter.tex" but it doesn't work.

The two files are in the same folder, and they are standalone files (with their \documentclass, \begin{document} ...)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8662/merge-two-pdf-files-output-by-latex ?

Comment: There is a "download pdf" button in the viewer windows. Download the paper and then use one of the methods shown in the linked answer above.

Comment: Alternatively, if one of the files isn't too long, you can just paste its tex code into the appropriate spot (and possibly reset appropriate counters).

Comment: @Teepeemm if the two documents have different `documentclass`, it's almost impossible to do that... Much better to create the PDFs and join them.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/426499/11604, but I  would  do simply `pdftk A.pdf B.pdf cat output C.pdf` to join A and B in C.