Subfiles with special packages in each
Recently I learned that I can add special commands for my subfiles, which will be invisible to others.
But I am wondering,  how to do that if my commands are located in special packages.
The question is as follows: suppose I have a document with, for example, 2 subfiles. I want to use one package only in one of my subfiles and let the othe subfile not know it.
So, for example, I want to add physics package to one.tex file and make it not added to the two.tex?
Is it possible to do so?
My document is the simplest:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\subfile{one.tex}
\subfile{two.tex}
\end{document}


Have you tried loading subfiles with teh [V1] option? I believe that will allow you to add those packages to the preamble of the subfile. (See https://ctan.uib.no/macros/latex/contrib/subfiles/subfiles.pdf for more information.)

@KennethOdle No, I haven't. Thank you, I'll try later!

If your real question is how to merge/combine several TeX documents and you are not really tied to the subfiles package, then search for latex combine documents or latex merge documents. The problem that one usually wants to solve is that the definitions for one document should not interfere with the ones from the other. The most reliable way is to concatenate the PDFs generated by the documents by some PDF tool. You can also do it within LaTeX with the package pdfpages that will allow you some postprocessing (like consistent page numbering).

See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8662/110998

In general, the answer is no: You cannot load packages selectively for one subfile but not for the other when processing them in one run. [For an exception from  this rule see below.]
Why? Each LaTeX run processes commands in preamble mode until some \begin{document} switches it to document mode. I'm not aware of any safe method to switch back to preamble mode for loading further packages, or to forget reliably a package that has already been loaded.
What you can do in a subfile is to load packages that are only available when processing the subfile standalone.
\documentclass[main]{subfiles}
\usepackage{some_package_if_this_is_the_main_file}
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}

However, when loading the file with \subfile from another file, some_package_if_this_is_the_main_file.sty will not be loaded. Not sure that there is a use case where this may still be useful.
Exception: If your 'package' contains just command definitions that would also work when executed in document mode, then you can use \input instead of \usepackage and load the file in the subfile after \begin{document}. Then its contents will be processed each time the subfile is processed, and since subfiles are included within a group, the commands are not available outside of the subfile. This is actually just a variation of the situation described in my answer to 'Subfiles with a special command in each'.
% main.tex
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\subfile{one.tex}
\subfile{two.tex}
\end{document}

% one.tex
\documentclass[main]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\input{commandsForOne.sty}% loads commandsForOne.sty
...
\end{document}

% two.tex
\documentclass[main]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\input{commandsForTwo.sty}% loads commandsForTwo.sty
...
\end{document}


Thank you! That is a very informative answer!
