# Insert PDF file in LaTeX document

Tags: pdf, pdfpages

I have a problem when I insert a PDF file in LaTeX:

```
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}

\includepdf[pages=-]{file.pdf}
```

The problem is that the PDF page is not centered:

[image: result]

I've tried to place tags `center`, but nothing works.

---

Thank you for your response.

I still have the same problem.

For a good layout, I have to do this:

```
\includepdf[pages=1,pagecommand={},offset=-2.5cm -3cm]{file.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=2,pagecommand={},offset=2.5cm -3cm]{file.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=3,pagecommand={},offset=-2.5cm -3cm]{file.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=4,pagecommand={},offset=2.5cm -3cm]{file.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=5,pagecommand={},offset=-2.5cm -3cm]{file.pdf}
```

This is very annoying. I want to insert a PDF of 50 pages, I can not insert page by page ...

I tried

```
\begin{figure}
 \centering 
 \includepdf[pages=-]{file.pdf}
\end{figure}
```

But all pages of the PDF are superimposed on one page!

And with `\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}`
I have an error :

`! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package graphicx`

Please help me!

P.S. I use a model given by my university.
In this model, we find this:

```
%----- Dimensions -----
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{2cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{2cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{\paperheight}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-5.7cm} % 24cm
\setlength{\textwidth}{\paperwidth}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{-4cm} % 17cm
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\headheight}{2cm}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\voffset}{-2.54cm}
\setlength{\hoffset}{-2.54cm}
\setlength{\footskip}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}
```

If I remove this:

```
\setlength{\voffset}{-2.54cm}
\setlength{\hoffset}{-2.54cm}
```

the layout of the PDF is OK, but the rest is bad!

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) of your code?

Comment: By default pages are centered and it works fine for me. So it looks as if either your pdf has curious margins or your pdfpages version has a bug. Beside this: pdfpages has a documentation which also contains a section which describes how to move the pdf around.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I found the solution :

```
\setboolean{@twoside}{false}
```

And

```
\includepdf[pages=-, offset=75 -75]{file.pdf}
```

And it works !

Comment: While it works, I preferred the solution bellow, that changes voffset and hoffset.

Comment: Works fine! Just need to change the offset a bit. More info on tweaking the offset is welcome.

Answer (score 131):

I did it this way with package `pdfpages`:

```
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={},width=\textwidth]{file.pdf}
```

Comment: It scaled the pages down to the available text width. If inserting A4 in A4, this will not work properly. The above option with @twoside is the best I could get so far.

Comment: I would like to keep the original page numbering, but also the new one.
I mean my thesis already has a numbering, on top, and I need to embed an article in the appendix. How can I keep both? One inside the other?

Comment: Though it's stated in words and in the question, it's better to be explicit: include a line in the preamble `\usepackage{pdfpages}`

Answer (score 30):

Try this:

```
\setlength{\voffset}{0cm}
\setlength{\hoffset}{0cm}

\includepdf[pages=-]{file.pdf}

\setlength{\voffset}{-2.54cm}
\setlength{\hoffset}{-2.54cm}
```

Then the pdf will be put in the page without the offsets of the rest of the document.

In case you are with a similar problem but do not know which are he actual offsets, you can create two new lengths, store the original values, and restore them again:

```
 \newlength{\originalVOffset}
 \newlength{\originalHOffset}
 \setlength{\originalVOffset}{\voffset}   
 \setlength{\originalHOffset}{\hoffset}

 \setlength{\voffset}{0cm}
 \setlength{\hoffset}{0cm}
 \includepdf[pages=-]{file}
 \setlength{\voffset}{\originalVOffset}
 \setlength{\hoffset}{\originalHOffset}
```

Answer (score 23):

I would say: put the page inside a `figure` environment and use the `\centering` command. It's action should be restricted to the figure.

```
\begin{figure}
 \centering 
 \includepdf[pages=-]{file.pdf}
\end{figure}
```

Note that a simple `\includegraphics{file.pdf}` should to the trick, no need for extra packages. i.e. this a working code for me:

```
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \centering 
 \includegraphics{file.pdf}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Moreover, this allows the use of additional scaling options such as `\includegraphics[scale=0.50]{file.pdf}`, etc.

Comment: Have you tried this? Moreover [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)'s `\includegraphics` doesn't really need the driver `pdftex` explicitly specified, since it's picked up by the method of compilation.

Comment: Oops! Typo, I'll edit my post to reflect that.
Otherwise, I never used pdfpage, but I used the includegraphics variant countless times :)

Comment: This actually only work if your PDF contains only one page. It won't create new pages for each of your PDF pages.

Comment: Indeed it won't.

Answer (score 19):

Try this. Compile it with `pdflatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{status-lua}
\end{document}
```

I tested with TeX Live 2012 (just updated several days ago) and it works fine.

Note: `status-lua` is one (of limited number of others) accessible PDF file (in the installed TeX distribution) that I can use for a demonstration purpose.

Comment: Best working option in particular regarding page geometry.