# How to make figure bigger in subfigures with width?

Tags: floats, subfloats, size

I want to make figures bigger in subfigures, but `scale` does not work when I use `width`. 
Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37597/13173
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164778/13173
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[page=1,width=.4\textwidth]{Rplots_male.pdf}
\caption{Cor males.}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[page=2,width=0.4\textwidth]{Rplots_male.pdf}
\caption{Cor new ECG males.}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Unsuccessful attempt to control the size of the figure

```
\includegraphics[page=1,width=.4\textwidth,scale=1.2]{Rplots_male.pdf}
```

OS: Debian 8.5
TeXLive: 2016

Comment: *How much* bigger do you want to make the graphs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\textwidth` or `\linewidth` refers to the width of the `subfigure`, not to the absolute text width. Therefore, `.4\textwidth` inside `.2\textwidth` becomes 20 % of the text width.

The maximum width is `\textwidth`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37597/13173
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164778/13173
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[page=1,width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Cor males.}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[page=2,width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Cor new ECG males.}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Very nice idea! I have always used scale manually for such basic thing, saves so much time now on. - -  Is there anything similar for `height=\pageheight`? - - I would like to have four such figures in one page.

Comment: @Masi The height is usually more complicate because the height of other elements need to be taken into account, such as the caption text, text/title before the figure.

Answer (score 5):

Some comments, in no particular order:

- *Inside* a `subfigure` environment of a given width -- say, `0.5\textwidth` -- the widths of `\textwidth` and `\linewidth` are relative to the width of the entire subfigure.
- No need to load the `graphicx` package explicitly if you use the `beamer` document class.
- The `subcaption` package loads the `caption` package automatically.
- I suggest that you set the widths of the `subfigure` environments to something like `0.45\textwidth` and that you maximize the horizontal distance between them via an `\hfill` directive. Inside each `subfigure`, set the width of the image file to `\linewidth`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer} % remove 'demo' option in real document
%\usepackage{graphicx} % is loaded automatically by beamer class
\usepackage{subcaption} % loads 'caption' automatically

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[page=1,width=\linewidth]{Rplots_male}
\caption{Cor males.}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill % maximize the separation between the two graphs
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[page=2,width=\linewidth]{Rplots_male}
\caption{Cor new ECG males.}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```