# How can I add a page (pdf) that takes the size of an A4 page in a document?

Tags: formatting, packages, page-breaking, templates

How can I add a page that takes the size of an A4 page in a document?

I use the package `\usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=3cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=3cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry}`.
I tried to add it that way

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside]{extreport}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.4}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{refstyle}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=3cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=3cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\footnotesize \nouppercase{\leftmark}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{image}
\end{figure}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\chapter{chapter one}
\section{text}
\chapter{chapter two}
\section{text}
\end{document}
```

But the way failed in the image (extension pdf) move to the second page when zoomed. It is not A4 size.

The following images illustrate

[image]
[image]

[image]

The image should be on the front page of A4 size and there are no margins.

Please help, thank you anyway.

Comment: Have you looked into https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105589/insert-pdf-file-in-latex-document already?

Comment: (1) unlearn that you have never heard of H placement for floats (it is not good for you,and irrelevant in this context), (2) you need to place it in the background, here is it in the foreground. A package like `eso-pic` provides a low level interface to add stuff to the background. There are other packages as well.

Comment: If you want to use this as a background to a page with other content, use [`eso-pic`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) or similar packages like @daleif suggested, see [How to create a background image on title page with LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46280/3323) for further information. If you only want to have this image on a separate page, with no further text on it, use [`pdfpages`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) as proposed by @ingli.

Comment: Alternatively to `eso-pic`, e.g. `tikz` does provide means to put stuff in the background, too.