# I'd like to put a full pdf page in my document, but it doesn't work!

Tags: pdf, input, pdfpages, include, includegraphics

i've got an issue.
I'm writing a LaTeX document, i would like to make a page of my final document as a pdf file (that is a text). I searched on this site but no one of the existing topic helped me.

I tried to use `\input`, `\include`, and `\includegrapics{file.pdf}` but it doesn't work.

If i use the latest command (`\includegraphics`) it looks like:
[image: results]

So the image respect my margins and my page style.

How can I solve this??

Thanks

Update with the code:

```
   \documentclass[11pt]{article}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage{fancyhdr}
   \usepackage{vmargin}
   \setmarginsrb{2 cm}{2.5 cm}{2 cm}{2.5 cm}{1 cm}{1.5 cm}{1 cm}{1.5 cm}
   \pagestyle{fancy}
   \fancyhf{}
   \rhead{}
   \lhead{}
   \cfoot{\thepage}
   \begin{document}
   \input{Lab3/Lab3}
   \newpage
   \includegraphics{Lab4/traccia4.pdf}
   \newpage
   \input{Lab4/Lab4}
   \end{document}
```

I'm working with \input.

Comment: Welcome into TeX.SE users' site. Welcome again to our site. Please can you put your complete code (see [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe)) or add the code you're working on? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, did you have look at this topic : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105589/insert-pdf-file-in-latex-document ?
It seems that the package `pdfpages` could solve your problem. See more over `pdfpages` on CTAN : https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages

Comment: Hi @Sebastiano Thanks for your kind welcome. I edited my question.

Comment: Hi @Piroooh i had a look at that topic, i will try again, but i though that there is a faster way to do it.

Comment: As @Piroooh suggests i tried the answer to that topic with :
       \usepackage{ifthen}
       \setboolean{@twoside}{false}
       \includepdf[pages=1, offset=75 -75]{Lab4/traccia4.pdf}

Comment: @MarcoFerrari, `\input` and `\include` bascally insert a `tex` file into another one so this is not what you need. You should use `pdfpages` for your needs

Answer (score 2):

You want to include a PDF file who is not a .tex file. The two commands `\input` and `\include` just put a .tex file at the position of the command. Really convenient to shorten a .tex project and separate parts but useless to include pdf.

`\includegraphics[]{}` is for picture. PDF file can act like a picture but the command will respect your previous geometry option. As if you put a normal picture.

What you are looking for is to include a PDF as a part of your PDF file. The [package](http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf) `pdfpages` can help you.

You do not have to include `ifthen` package. Try this following code :

```
   \documentclass[11pt]{article}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage{fancyhdr}
   \usepackage{vmargin}
   \setmarginsrb{2 cm}{2.5 cm}{2 cm}{2.5 cm}{1 cm}{1.5 cm}{1 cm}{1.5 cm}
   \pagestyle{fancy}
   \fancyhf{}
   \rhead{}
   \lhead{}
   \cfoot{\thepage}
   \begin{document}
   \input{Lab3/Lab3}
   \newpage
   \includepdf[pages=-, offset=50 -75]{Lab4/traccia4.pdf}
   \newpage
   \input{Lab4/Lab4}
   \end{document}
```

And change the `offset` option as you want. First value sets an horizontal space and second one a vertical space.

Answer (score 1):

As @Piroooh suggests i tried the answer to that topic with :

```
   \usepackage{ifthen}
   \setboolean{@twoside}{false}
   \includepdf[pages=1, offset=75 -75]{Lab4/traccia4.pdf}
```

And it works, but it's not the same page as the pdf file, it is good, but a little different.

Comment: Look at the pdfpages package